# Check file type?

Tags: php, file-upload

I need to check a file's type on upload to make sure it's an image. What I'm thinking of doing is checking the MIME file type(from `$_FILE`) and then checking that against the extension. Something like:

```
function checkType($file){

    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES[$file]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $mime = $_FILES[$file]['type'];

    if($mime == "image/jpg" || $mime == "image/jpeg"){

        if($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg"){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    if($mime == "image/gif"){

        if($ext == "gif"){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    if($mime == "image/png"){

        if($ext == "png"){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Is this a good approach? Suggestions?

Also, how would I go about getting the width of the image before it's finally uploaded to the server?

Answer (score 3):

You should never rely on the content type provided by `$_FILE` as it's set by the browser, not by your server.

If you're expecting images, you should use [`getimagesize()`](https://www.php.net/getimagesize) to get the type of the image.

**Example:**

```
$imagedata = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$mime = $imagedata['mime'];
```

You should then make sure that `$mime` isn't empty and that it contains a mime type that you want.

Here's an example using the Google logo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/9GBDf9

Comment: Great thanks. Can I use `getimagesize` for the width of the image as well?

Comment: @user811348 - Sure can! Have a look at the documentation. The first and second members of the `$imagedata` array above contain the height and width. :)

Comment: Awesome. One thing, though. It's not working. Even if I just simplify it down to just echoing the mime type, it returns nothing.

Comment: Does the image have to be uploaded to the server in a permanent location before I can run `getimagesize()` on it?

Comment: @user811348 - No. You should be able to do this from the temporary location too. As long as PHP can read it. If the `mime` key is empty, then the file isn't valid. You should try doing `var_dump($imagedata)` to see what the array contains.

Comment: @user811348 - Can you output the path to the image and make sure that it exists. `FALSE` is returned on failure so I have a feeling that the path is wrong. In the example above, I'm using `$_FILES[$file]['name']` from your function above but depending on what you pass to your function, `$file` may not exist and make `getimagesize` fail.

Comment: The function was only when I thought this process more complicated. It's been removed from the script, and replaced with `$imagedata = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['name']);` which is before `move_uploaded_file()`

Comment: @user811348 - You should try to add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of you code so that PHP shows you any error messages. There may be something else wrong. Can you also do `var_dump($_FILES)` and confirm that there is a key called "image" in the array?

Comment: To answer your question though, yes, I can. It's `/tmp/phpw0iw5w`.

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES)` returns an array: `array(1) { ["image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(41) "testimage1.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpKPP4TF" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(333515) } }`

Comment: @user811348 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1564/discussion-between-francois-deschenes-and-user811348)

Answer (score 2):

No, its bad. Mime type could not match actual file contents. To be sure what kind of uploaded file you received (or if its actually an image) you need to check file contents.

Try function like [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) for example. If it will return valid data then you have an image.